# Show a frame untill other one is invoked

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF Application and I'm trying to display a frame while other one is prepared.
For example, there are cases where I have to start a device.

For this, I send as a parameter, a delegate, which I want to run after displaying the loading frame. The loading frame is showed but is locked, is not spinning.
For this I have this Code:

```
CoreBaseConfiguration.LoadingFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { ExecOnLoad.Invoke(ObjectToBind); }));
```

**CoreBaseConfiguration.LoadingFrame** is a static field that holds the Loading frame
and **ExecOnLoad** is the method which I want to run while the Loading frame is displayed.

*ExecOnLoad will hide the Loading frame and will load another frame behind the Loading frame.

Comment: Why do you think it is not spinning while the thread is occupied loading `ExecOnLoad`? It's isn't ran on a separate thread.. Dispatcher.Invoke will run the method on where it is created on. The UI thread in this case.

Comment: Can I run it on another thread?

Comment: You could use the `Task.Run()` to execute it parallel. But if you're not on the UI thread, you are not allowed to manipulate UI. You can use the Dispatcher.Invoke to execute something on the UI thread then.